# How do I convert Python+Flask list of objects to JS list of objects?

Tags: javascript, object, flask, type-conversion, javascript-objects

Here's a Flask app which contains a list of objects.

```
from flask import *

app = Flask(__name__)

class Entry: 

    def __init__(self, name, surname):
        self.name = name
        self.surname = surname

entries = [] 

entries.append(Entry('Paul', 'McCartney'))
entries.append(Entry('John', 'Lennon'))
entries.append(Entry('George', 'Harrison'))
entries.append(Entry('Ringo', 'Starr')) 

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', entries = entries) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Here's the index.html file:

```
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
    <script>

    var entries = "{{entries[0].name}}"
    console.log(entries)

    </script> 
</body>

</html>
```

In this case, everything works fine and console output is `Paul` as expected.

But when I change the code to this,

```
var entries = "{{entries}}"
console.log(entries[0].name)
```

The console outputs `undefined`

If we say `console.log(entries)` in this case, it returns the following:

```
[&lt;__main__.Entry object at 0x1065a2278&gt;, &lt;__main__.Entry object at 0x1065a22b0&gt;, 
&lt;__main__.Entry object at 0x1065a22e8&gt;, &lt;__main__.Entry object at 0x1065a2208&gt;]
```

I assume that it's necessary to convert this list of objects to JS format somehow, am I right? How to do this properly? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`entries` is a list of `Entry` Python objects. The best way to get this into a JavaScript object is to use JSON. JSON is a great format for transfer between systems, but you need to serialise your list do that. `json.dumps()` only works with simple data, not user defined classes. What you can do is convert your list of `Entry` objects to a list of dictionary objects.

main.py:

```
from flask import *
import json

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', entries=json.dumps([ob.__dict__ for ob in entries]))
```

Then in your html page you can use the `safe` filter inside your template. This tells jinja2 that the content is safe to render as is, and not to escape the html/javascript.

index.html:

```
<script>
    var entries = {{ entries|safe }}
    console.log(entries)
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I faced this error as well.
The best way(I think is) by converting it to a JSON object and sending it.

flask:

```
import json

@app.route('/')
def index():
    jobj = {'data' : entries }
    return render_template('index.html', res=json.dumps(jobj))
```

javascript:

```
var res = JSON.parse('{{ res | safe }}');
console.log(res.data);
```